# Why am I able to cache a component that imports several components, but cannot cache just a single child component?

Tags: vue.js

This works:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <keep-alive including="home">
    <router-view />
  </keep-alive>
  </div>
</template>
```

**router.vue**

```
 routes: [
     {
     path: "/",
     name: "home",
     component: homeView
   },
```

This seems to be caching the entire homeView component as expected.  However if remove this and add keep-alive within the homeView component itself, it does not cache the individual component that I am trying to cache.

What I'm trying to do is instead of caching an entire view, cache just a single component of that view.  So instead of caching homeView, I just want to cache NewComponent.

**homeView.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="vue-main">
    <NavBar></NavBar>
    <h1><b>Home</b></h1>
        <transition name="fade" appear mode="out-in">
          <keep-alive>
            <NewComponent @loading=updateLoading></NewComponent>
          </keep-alive>
        </transition>
    <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from "../NavBar.vue";
import NewComponent from "../NewComponent.vue";

export default {
  name: "homeView",
  data () {
    return {
      loading: true,
    }
  },
  components: {
    NavBar,
    NewComponent
  },
  methods: {
    updateLoading(val) {
      this.loading = !val;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How do I cache NewComponent, and why is it allowing me to cache home but not NewComponent?

Comment: Do I need to pass the loading key to keep-alive ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you achieve the desired result but I can explain a little about how `keep-alive` works.

`keep-alive` is a component. You can see the source code for it here:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/3b8925bc7973bb71b33374281db10a945ca9854e/src/core/components/keep-alive.js#L53

It might all look a bit alien but a key part to note is the `created` hook. In there it creates a cache that will be used to store the children. The cache lives on that particular `keep-alive` component instance.

So for the children to benefit from `keep-alive` it's necessary for the `keep-alive` component itself to be retained. The cache isn't shared between instances, it is local to that particular `keep-alive` instance.

So going back to the template in the question:

```html
<keep-alive>
  <NewComponent @loading=updateLoading></NewComponent>
</keep-alive>
```

If `NewComponent` is removed using a `v-if` then the `keep-alive` will keep it around in its cache, ready for when the `v-if` flips back to `true`. However, if you navigate between pages then the whole of `homeView` will be destroyed, including the `keep-alive` component and its cache.